# Animation set, shake effect

Tags: android, android-animation, kotlin

I try to shake animation my view, i write this code, but It seems to me that it is possible to make it easier

```
 var animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
    var objectRotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(shake, "rotation", -5f, 5f)
    objectRotateAnimator.apply {
        repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
        repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
        duration = 70
        interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    }

    var objectTranslateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(shake, "translate", -5f, 5f)
    objectTranslateAnimator.apply {
        repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
        repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
        duration = 70
        interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    }

    start_shake.setOnClickListener {
        animatorSet.play(objectRotateAnimator).with(objectTranslateAnimator)
        animatorSet.start()
    }
```

How can i do it more simple?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract some functions and fields to reduce the duplication:

```
private val linearInterpolator = LinearInterpolator()

private fun shakeAnimator(propertyName: String) =
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(shake, propertyName, -5f, 5f).apply {
            repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
            repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
            duration = 70
            interpolator = linearInterpolator
        }
```

Then it will just look like:

```
start_shake.setOnClickListener {
    AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(shakeAnimator("rotation")).with(shakeAnimator("translate"))
        start()
    }
}
```

The good method names have removed the need for intermediate variables which has shortened the code further.